# roslaunch args with double quote " "

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I like to use roslaunch to start a rosbag recording with regular expression arguments.
How to I substitute the double quote "" to avoid xml problems
The following launch code is **NOT working**.

```
<launch>  
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" name="rosbag" args="record -e "(.*)image_raw"  "(.*)camera_info" " />
</launch>
```

Any ideas

Greetings
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12812/roslaunch-args-with-double-quote-%22-%22/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2012-01-30

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The correct entity escape in XML for quot is `&quot;`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could also use single quotes, ', inside the outer set of "".

---

Originally posted by [raahlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/966/raahlb/) with karma: 317 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2012-01-31**:
Thanks it worked with: